# How do I go to the About Page without linking the a href?

Tags: html, css

I want to go to the about section without needing to link to another .html file. Originally, I tried *a href = "About.html"* but when clicking on the About Button it just links to that page ignoring the index.html page where all the main content is. Next, I tried *a href = #About* which did nothing when the about button was pressed.

```css
section{
    padding: 39px 0;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1225px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 24px;
}

.headline-description h5{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.Content{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: bisque;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.about-button{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #225522;
    border: 1px solid #225522;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.the-life-of-a-chef{
    background-color: #2255cc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CHEF</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asdf.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="Content" id="Content">
        <div class="container">
            <!--Website Name-->
            <h1 class="headline">C H E F</h1>
            <div class="headline-description">
                <div class="seperator">
                    <!--Underline Chef / Cutlery Icon in middle-->
                    <div class="line line-left"></div>
                    <div class="cutlery"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i></div>
                    <div class="line line-right"></div>
                </div>

                    <h5>Life of a chef</h5>
                    <a href="#About" class="button about-button">About</a>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>

<section class="the-life-of-a-chef">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="rest-button">
            <div class="Lorem-text">
                <div class="LifeOfChefHeadline">
                    <h2 class="AboutHeadline">
                        <span class="About">About</span>
                    </h2>
                    <h1 class="headline headline-gold">The Life Of A Chef</h1>
                </div>
```

Comment: "Does nothing" > Does the url change to "...#About" or no?  Also, is your html snippet a partial or full text copy?  Because that's invalid html.  The second `<section>` tag should be inside the body tag.

Comment: #About links to the ID of an element, not its class. You have no element whose ID is `About` in your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `id="About"` to the section you want to scroll to.
See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ud3k2ztv/